# Sphinx 3.1.1. DocStore seems to fail

Tags: sphinx

I have recently upgraded to Sphinx 3.1.1. to be able to use DocStore. For my index I use the following configuration:

```
index RT_TEST
{
    type            = rt
    path            = /mnt/data001/RT_TEST
    rt_field        = Name
    rt_field        = Extension
    rt_field        = Content
    rt_field        = Tags
    rt_attr_uint    = Reference
    rt_attr_uint    = FileSize
    rt_attr_uint    = LastModified
    rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedYear
    rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedMonth
    rt_attr_uint    = LastModifiedDay
    stored_fields   = Content
    rt_mem_limit    = 1024M
    charset_table   = A..Z, a..z, 0..9, _, ;, %
    ondisk_attrs    = pool
}

searchd
{
    listen              = 9306:mysql41
    log                 = /var/sphinx/searchd.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    max_children        = 30
    pid_file            = /var/run/searchd.pid
    max_packet_size     = 128M
    binlog_path         = /mnt/data001
}
```

Important to realize is that I insert encrypted content meeting the `charset_table` directive of my index configuration. Still, the insert fails since the queried value differs from the inserted value...

For instance, the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO RT_TEST(id, Name, Extension, Content, Tags, Reference, FileSize, LastModified, LastModifiedYear, LastModifiedMonth, LastModifiedDay) VALUES(1774, 'DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7WtXmnUHLGt2', '7A5A5Q', 'FAUsvCA% FAUsvCA% BA8s Fg8sqy4D BA8s9jcJzE5TXysiVnBiOjr8YRE% AB0% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% DgM% AgMjtiQ% Ag84vQ%% UFo% CwMsrTEDzA%% DgsmvCAI EQ8% CAMnrA%% AgUtqg%% CwUlvSs% BA8uuTYSx0Q% EA8woioDyQ%% EAss Eg8wvTYH AQ81vSAV1g%% CQc% Aw8s BwssrCQK Dx4ntTY% Eg8% BQInuy4DzA%% Cwsjqg%% AgM2 EQsx Cw82 Aw8s FA8mvSs% Agsjqg%% CQQ4vQ%% FQE3 Ags2uQ%% CAMnrA%% BQUwqiAF1g%% Cw8nqg%% DwQ% Dg82 FRMxrCADzw%% FR4ttiE% HAMotg%% Axg% EAUtqg%% Aw8s Fgsjqg%% CRgmvTcV Ag84vQ%% Dx4ntTY% FRMxrCALw15fbDgv CAMnrA%% AQ8xvSkDwV5Teikj DwE% HAsu Axg0tyoU HAUwvyAI Ags2 Ag84vQ%% CRo% Ag8% DwQ0tywFxw%% EAss AA8gqjAH0EM% AQ8hqiACy15Teikj AQsjrA%% EQUwvCAI HAsu DwQ% Ag8% BAMotCQBxw%% EAsx CRolvSsJz09Y EQUwvCAI AxIhrTYD0Q%% EAUtqg%% Dg82 CQQlvSgHyQ%% C0Q09iI% BA8s ABgttQ%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% FQ8srA%% Eh8nqyEH2w%% AA8gqjAH0FM% V10% VFpz7Q%% VVB27Q%% Fgc% EgU% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% FgYn Fg8sqy4D BQk% FAUsvCA% BA8s Fg8sqy4D FR8gsiAF1g%% AB0% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% DQMsvA%% FA8luTcC0Q%% Cw82 EBgrvSsCx0ZfdTAi ARgtvTEDzA%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y FQ8j ABgnsSIO1g%% DwcytzcS CRonqiQSzVg% FAUqtCwB CA8mvTcKw0RS BEQ0 EQ8ntiQ% VFpy BB8rtCEPzE0% EQ8ntiQ% VV5w EgU1vTc% Bw%% V1gktA%% VVpz6g%% CAA% FAU2rCAUxktb Eg8u VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VFhx AAs6 VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VF5w AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% ER019jcJykZfeHUkV24% ABgttQ%% Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% Eg8wvTYHjFlXfTQreGpnK32n1;CdScZYKYkp9ov4zQ%% FQ8srA%% CwUsvCQf AA8gqjAH0FM% V1w% VFpz7Q%% UlBy4A%% Fgc% EgU% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y FR8gsiAF1g%% AB0% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% DgM% AgMjtiQ% Dw%% Dgs0vQ%% FRotsyAI EQM2sA%% DAsxtys% BwQm Dg8% Dxk% Bx0jqiA% EgIjrA%% Dw%% AgU% CAU2 Dgs0vQ%% EQ8gqywSxw%% BwkhvTYV CQQ% FAUqtCwBTZWLbA%% FQM2vQ%% Bxgn HwU3 BwguvQ%% EgU% CQg2uSwI CwU0vSgDzF4% FA8ytzcS0Q%% CQQ% Dx4ntQ%% FQ%% Dww% Dw%% CA8nvA%% EgIntQ%% BQss HwU3 FgYnuTYD Dgs0vQ%% Fg8sqy4D FhgtriwCxw%% AB8wrC0D0A%% DwQktzcLw15fcDU% AAUw EgIrqw%% AwQ2qjw% UEcouSs% FR4tuy4% BQU3tjE% Eg8wvTYH UFo% CwsrtA%% Eg8wvTYH Cws% U0dz9XdWkx8% V1947X0% Cws% U0dz9XdWkx8% V1x46XQ% EgIjti4% HwU3 Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% Fh8wuy0H0UNYeA%% BxkxtyYPw15T Ul5y9XdSmgcGLmx; Hll06w%% ABgttQ%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% FQ8srA%% CwUsvCQf AA8gqjAH0FM% V1w% VFpz7Q%% X1By6A%% Bwc% EgU% Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% FR8gsiAF1g%% FA8% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% Ag8jqg%% Eg8wvTYH FQ8n Bx42uSYOx04% DQMsvA%% FA8luTcC0Q%% Cw82 EBgrvSsCx0ZfdTAi ARgtvTEDzA%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y FQ8j ABgnsSIO1g%% DwcytzcS CRonqiQSzVg% FAUqtCwB CA8mvTcKw0RS BEQ0 EQ8ntiQ% VFpy BB8rtCEPzE0% EQ8ntiQ% VV5w EgU1vTc% Bw%% V1gktA%% VVpz6g%% CAA% FAU2rCAUxktb Eg8u VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VFhx AAs6 VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VF5w AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% ER019jcJykZfeHUkV24% ABgttQ%% Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% Eg8wvTYHjFlXfTQreGpnK32n1;CdScZYKYkp9ov4zQ%% FQ8srA%% CwUsvCQf AA8gqjAH0FM% V1w% VFpz7Q%% VVBy6A%% Fgc% EgU% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y FR8gsiAF1g%% AB0% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% DgM% AgMjtiQ% AgU% HwU3 Dgs0vQ%% Bw%% FQInvTE% EgIjrA%% FQItrzY% EgIn EAsx BQIjqiID0Q%% EgInoQ%% Bxgn CA8jqikf AgU3uikD EQIjrA%% EgInoQ%% Exk3uSkK2w%% Bxgn Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% Fh8wuy0H0UNYeA%% BxkxtyYPw15T Ul5y9XdSmgcGLmx; Hll06w%% ABgttQ%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% FQ8srA%% CwUsvCQf AA8gqjAH0FM% V1w% VFpz7Q%% XlBx7w%% Bwc% EgU% Eg8wvTYH FQsgtyk% FR8gsiAF1g%% DwQ2vTcCx1lfeDU% DwQ0tywFxw%% DAssrSQU2w%% VFpz7Q%% Ag8jqg%% Eg8wvTYH BQss HwU3 CQE% EgIn Bx42uSYOx04% FQInvTE% EgIjti4V DQMsvA%% FA8luTcC0Q%% Cw82 EBgrvSsCx0ZfdTAi ARgtvTEDzA%% AgMjtiQ% AgMntCwV0U9Y FQ8j ABgnsSIO1g%% DwcytzcS CRonqiQSzVg% FAUqtCwB CA8mvTcKw0RS BEQ0 EQ8ntiQ% VFpy BB8rtCEPzE0% EQ8ntiQ% VV5w EgU1vTc% Bw%% V1gktA%% VVpz6g%% CAA% FAU2rCAUxktb Eg8u VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VFhx AAs6 VVs% V1o% VFI% VF8% VF5w AgMjtiRIxkNTczI0S2ZnH51RoVnYBIbuBLY% ER019jcJykZfeHUkV24% FgYjuyA% CQw% DB8wsTYCy0lCdjQp EgIn CA82sCAUzktYeyg% FAU2rCAUxktb EhgjvCA% FA8lsTYSx1g% FAU2rCAUxktb CBhs6nFWmhMALWs% EgIn Ah82uy0% AAUwryQUxkNYeA%% BQUsvCwSy0VYbA%% DwQ% EgIn Cgs2vTYS EA8wqywJzA%% Ag8ytzYP1k9S BBM% AA8svT0% Bx4% EgIn FA8lsTYS0FM% CQw% EgIn AgMxrDcPwV4% BQU3qjE% Bx4% FAU2rCAUxktb FQIjtCk% BxoytDw% EgIn BQUsvCwSy0VYbA%% EQMutA%% BA8% FQ8srA%% EgU% HwU3 CQQ% FA8zrSAV1g%% FhgrriwKx01Te3QkV21vNrJfYupkLoM% DwQktzcLw15fcDU% Cws7 BA8% BQUsrCQPzE9S DwQ% EgIrqw%% Cw8xqyQBxw%% BwQm FhgtrCAF1k9S BBM% Bw%% FhgtviAV0UNZcTor FhgrriwKx01T CRg% EQItqyA% AgMxuykJ0V9Eeg%% BBM% Bw%% Cgs1 Dww% HwU3 Bxgn CAU2 EgIn Bw4mqiAV0U9T DwQmsSYH1k9S DwQ% EgIrqw%% Cw8xqyQBxw%% HwU3 Cws7 CAU2 BQUyoQ%% CRg% Ag8usTMD0A%% EgIrqw%% Cw8xqyQBxw%% EgU% BwQ7tysD DwQ% FR8hsA%% BQsxvQ%% HwU3 FQItrSkC Ag8xrDcJ2w%% EgIrqw%% Cw8xqyQBxw%% BwQm CAU2sSMf Exk% DwcvvSEPw15TcyI% DwQ2vTcIx14% A0cvuSwK CA8rrC0D0A%% AR8jqiQI1k9TbA%% EgIn BQUsviwCx0RCdjorUXdw CAUw EgIn DwQ2vSIUy15P CRg% FhgtqCAU FA8hvSwW1g%% CQw% EgIn Cw8xqyQBx1k% FQ8srA%% FKn0sCkPxQ%% AgUnqw%% CAU2 BxkxrSgD BwQ7 CgMjuiwKy15P AAUw EgItqyA% BQMwuzAL0V5XcTgiSw%% Dww% EgIn Bw4mqiAV0U9T CQw% EgIrqw%% Cw8xqyQBxw%% AgUnqw%% CAU2 BQUsqyAI1g%% EgU% EgIn Exkn CQw% DwQ2vTcIx14% A0cvuSwK BwQm Cw8xqyQBxw%% FA8htzcCy0RR FgYnuTYD CAU2sSMf Exk% DwcvvSEPw15TcyI% EAsx VFpz7Q%% Ags2rSg% CRgmvTcI10dbeik% FA82rTcI Bw4vsSs% CwMs FA82rTcI DwQgtzAIxg%% BQInuy4% EQswvS0J11lT CwMs FA82rTcI Fh82uTIH2w%% EQswvS0J11lT CwMs EgA6 CgsgvSkV FQE3 DgMxrCoU2w%% FR4tuy4% BQInuy4% EwQuvTYV Fg8sqy4D BwkhtzAI1ktUcz4% AAUw FgMhsw%% Axgwtzc% AQ8wtSQI2w%% CgsgvSkV BwcjoioI CgsgvSkV CwsrtDY% BwgtrTE% EwQptioRzA%% CRgmvTcV CRgmvTc% BQIjtiID0Q%% DwQ% CRgmvTc% Dg8jvA%% Ags2uQ%% Bw4mqiAV0Q%% CRgmvTc% BQIjtiID0Q%% DwQ% Dx4ntSkPzE8% Vg%% Dx4ntQ%% CgMsvQ%% CR82 CQw% FR4tuy4% Dx4ntQ%% CgMsvQ%% BQIjtiID EgIn FR4jrDAV CQw% Bw%% FR4tuy4% Dx4ntQ%% CR4qvTcV EQM2sA%% FA8vuTcN0Q%% FA8vuTcN0Q%% EQ8nsw%% VA%% U0couStLkx8% FFhw6n1elx0E V1o% V1o% UEcouSs% FR4tuy4% BQU3tjE% Eg8wvTYH UFo% CwsrtA%% Eg8wvTYH Cws% U0dz9XdWkx8% V1947X0% Cws% U0dz9XdWkx8% V1x46XQ% UUcouSs% VFhx6HxRlRI% VVo% VVo% VA%% CwsrtA%% EAMhsyw% AgM% UEdz9XdWkx8% V1J46nA% XkcouSs% VFhw4Xxemx8% Vw%% XkcouSs% VFhx6XVXkh0% VQ%% Vw%% X0couSs% VFhx6XVXkxo% VQ%% VQ%% X0couSs% VFhx6Hxekhw% Vw%% EQ8nsw%% VQ%% V1hvsiQIjxsD VFhx6H1UkBM% VVo% VVo% V18% V1lvsiQI VFhx6XVXlRw% VQ%% Vw%% V1lvsiQI VFhx6XVXkxI% Vw%% V1lvsiQI VFhx6XVXkx8% Vw%% V1lvsiQI VFhx6XVXkxg% VA%% Vw%% V1lvsiQI VFhx6XVXkxk% Vw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XRUlBM% VA%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XVemxw% VA%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XVfkhg% Vw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XVemx0% Vw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XVUmx0% VQ%% Vw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJRkx0% Uw%% Uw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJQlB0% VA%% VA%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJSkR4% VQ%% VQ%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJVmhM% Vw%% Vw%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJVkx4% Xg%% Xg%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJUmxs% VA%% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJUmxI% VA%% CgsgvSkPzE0% EgA6 CR82uioTzE4% BAU6vTY% V1xvsiQI VFhx6XJRkBw% Vw%% V1xvsiQI Ag9y6HELzw%% V18% V18% V1o% V1xvsiQI FFlz6XdXlg%% V18% UFo% V1o% V1xvsiQI Ag9y6nULzw%% V18% V18% V1o% V1xvsiQI Ag9z6nVXkx8% V18% X1o% V1o% EQ8nsw%% Vl4% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVlBo% Uw%% Uw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJRkx8% UA%% UA%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVkxg% VA%% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJRkB4ZLWl0CTQ6ZygcJiCK3W8vGyk% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJSkB0% VQ%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJRkR0dLWl0CTQ6b5Q% VA%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVkxwdLWl0CTQ9a_I% VA%% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVkxkdLWl0CTQ7Zs3zC;c6n28q2RU% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVkhgdLWl0CTQ7Zp7Ntwb02r3fPhA% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJVkhIdLWl0CTQ6b4BTBpomHInCJM8% Vw%% V1NvsiQI VFhx6XJRkxwdLWl0CTQ6b2g% VA%% Vw%% VFpvsiQI FFt06HRXlw%% V18% UFo% V1o% VFtvsiQI FFhw63RTkRIF VFo% V18% Uw%% VFtvsiQI FA82rTcIxU9ZezI0 V1o% V1o% Uw%% VFtvsiQI FA82rTcI10EGL2oqVQ%% V18% Ul8% V18% VFhvsiQI Ulpz6HFQlxM% UVJy CgUtqyA% CgUjvCwIxQ%% BQUsrCQPzE9E UFo% CwMsqw%% CQwksSYD UVhy CwMsqw%% EQswvS0J11lT VFlvsiQI VFhx6nFWlR4% Ug%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nZVlh4% VQ%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nVfkRo% VQ%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nZVlhs% VQ%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nZVkR8% Uw%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nBflx4% Ug%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nNVkhI% Vw%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6nVfkxw% Ug%% VFlvsiQI VFhx6XJVkhMZLGtyFzc6bg%% Vw%% VFlvsiQI FFhw6nNTkBgC Ul8% VVo% V18% EQ8nsw%% Vl8% VFxvsiQI Ulpz6HFQlxI% UVJy CgUtqyA% CgUjvCwIxQ%% BQUsrCQPzE9E UFo% CwMsqw%% CQwksSYD UVhy CwMsqw%% EQswvS0J11lT VF1vsiQI VFhx6nNVkhw% VQ%% VQ%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflRI% VA%% VA%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nxSmxM% Vw%% Vw%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflBk% VA%% Vw%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBfkxw% VQ%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBRmxw% VFhx6nNVkh4% VA%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflBg% VFhx6nNWlxk% VA%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflB8% Vw%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nNVkxo% Vw%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nNVkhk% VFhx6nBflBo% VA%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nNVkxs% Vw%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflB0% VFhx6nNWlh8% VQ%% VF1vsiQI VFhx6nBflR0% VFhx6nBekB8% VA%% VF1vsiQI FAsvuXdRkhs% V1o% V1o% V1o% VF1vsiQI EwFy6HELzw%% V18% U1o% V1o% VF1vsiQI FAsvondRkhs% V1o% V18% V1o% VFJvsiQI VFhx6nNVkh8% VQ%% VFJvsiQI VFhx6nBfkxI% VQ%% DwQhtDACy0RR EgIrqw%% CgMsvQ%% DwQ0tywFx04% CQQ% VVpt6HQ% EQ8nsw%% Vlw% VUckvSc% VFhx63dQlh0% Xg%% Xg%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRlR0% Vw%% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dQlhs% Vw%% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRkBM% VA%% VA%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRlRo% Vw%% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRkRk% Vw%% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dQkRIdLWl0CzE;a7M% VA%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRlBIdLWl0CzE_azw% VA%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRlxw% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63FUkRo% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dRlxk% Vw%% VUckvSc% VFhx63dQlxodLWl0CzE_bkE% VA%% UkckvSc% VFhx63FUkRM% Ug%% UkckvSc% VFhx63ZelxI% Ug%% UkckvSc% VFhx63dQlh4% VQ%% UkckvSc% VFhx63dQlh8% VQ%% UkckvSc% FA82uykPwUJP V1o% V1o% V1o% UkckvSc% FA826HFWkBsD V1o% VV8% V1o% U0ckvSc% FA826ndVkxoOJmw% VFo% U1o% U1o% UEckvSc% VFhx63JSlB8% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx631Vlx0% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx631Vlx8dLWl0CzQ9ae8% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx631VlBo% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx63xXkR0% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx631VlxM% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx631VlB4% VA%% UEckvSc% VFhx631Vlxw% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx63xXkRw% Ug%% UEckvSc% VFhx7HRRkBk% VQ%% UEckvSc% VFhx7HRRkB0% VA%% UEckvSc% VFhx7HRRkB8% Uw%% UEckvSc% FA826ndVkxoOJmw% Ul8% Ulo% UFo% EQ8nsw%% UQ%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSlxw% UQ%% UQ%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRRkxw% VA%% Uw%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSmh8% VA%% Uw%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRRkBo% Vw%% Ug%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRQkRg% Vw%% Ug%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSlx4% Vw%% Ug%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRRkxM% VQ%% V1g% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSmh4% VQ%% V1g% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSlx0% VA%% Xg%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRSlRI% VA%% Xg%% V1pvviAE VFhx7HVRlhg% VFhx7HRSlxk% VQ%% V1g% V1pvviAE VFhx7HRRkBs% VFhx7HRSlxg% VA%% Xg%% V1tvviAE VFhx7HVRkR0% Ug%% V1tvviAE VFhx7HVRkBk% Ug%% V1tvviAE VFhx7HVRkh8% Ug%% V1tvviAE VFhx7HVRkRI% Ug%% V1tvviAE VFhx7HVRkRM% Ug%% V1lvviAE VFhx7XRUkRgdLWl0DTI7b_FgTfqV5NfXkDQ% Ug%% V1lvviAE VFhx7XRQkB4dLWl0DTMwa8o% Ug%% V1lvviAE VFhx7HBRkhg% VA%% V1lvviAE VFhx7XRVkhs% Uw%% V1lvviAE VFhx7XdWmhw% VFhx7HJWmxo% Ug%% VFhx7XdWmxsdLWl0DDY_bc7vhv1tUNnExD4% Ug%% VFhx7XdWmx4dLWl0DDY;aptefrABxl_rE9U% Ug%% VFhx7XdWmhkdLWl0DTE5ZzASMD2MWREPqxc% Ug%% VFhx7HBRlxw% Ug%% VFhx7XRWlBk% Ug%% VFhx7HFSlB4% Ug%% VFhx7XVelh0dLWl0DTE5Zhnz;us2xm4e8uNVWaCI7x0hr7g% Ug%% VFhx7XVelx4% Ug%% VFhx7HBQkBk% Ug%% VFhx7XVelBw% Ug%% VFhx7HRRkB4% VQ%% Ag8hvSgEx1g% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% VF0% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% Vg%% FA8gvSYFww%% BxoyvSkJ VA%% CwMsrTED0Q%% Fg8w CgsgvSk% FA8gvSYFww%% BxoyvSkJ VA%% CwMsrTED0Q%% Fg8w CgsgvSk% FA8gvSYFww%% BxoyvSkJ FA8gvSYFww%% BxoyvSkJ VA%% CwMsrTED0Q%% Fg8w CgsgvSk% FQInvTFX EBgrvTYL Vw%% FgsutCASzktUejc% Dxk% FR4jtiEHw1hS', '', 11, 1021089, 1503999582, 2017, 8, 29);
```

Leads to the following query value when I query the value with: `SELECT content FROM RT_TEST WHERE id=1774;` I get the value:

```
FAUsvCA% FAUsvCA% BA8s Fg8sqy4D BA8s9jcJzE5TXysiVnBiOjr8YRE% AB0% Fg8sqy4D BQUvqCkHy0RC AAUwtQ%% EgIn DgUuvCwIxQ%% BQU% DgM% Ag8jtg%% Dw%% EgItrSIO1g%% Dw%% BwYwvSQC2w%% AQs0vQ%% HwU3 BwQ% BwQxryAU CQQ% EgIrqw%% BQUvqCkHy0RC BB82 BQsstioS AAMsvA%% BwQ7 AwcjsSk% ABgttQ%% CxM% FQMmvQ%% FQU% Bx4% AAMwqzE% CxM% BxottCoBy1BTbA%% EQ8% Dgs0vQ%% DwQ0vTYSy01Xaz4j EgIrqw%% BQUvqCkHy0RC BBM% BQInuy4PzE0% CR8w FgI7qywFw0Y% FR4tuy4% BwkhtzcCy0RR EgU% CR8w Bw4vsSsP0V5Efi8uTmY% FR4tuy4% AAUwrDAIw15TcyI% EgInqyA% AgU% Cws2uy0% BwYxtw%% EgIn CB8vuiAU CQw% BAU6vTY% EQIruy0% FQItrSkC Dgs0vQ%% BA8ntg%% FgMhsyAC AAUw EgIrqw%% FQIrqCgDzF5F AgUnqw%% Cws2uy0% EgIn CB8vuiAU CQw% BAU6vTY% EQ8% FQItrSkC Dgs0vQ%% BA8ntg%% FgMhsywIxQ%% BwkhtzcCy0RR EgU% EgIrqw%% DwQktzcLw15fcDU% Dw%% BQss CQQuoQ%% BQUsuykTxk8% EgIjrA%% EQ8% Dgs0vQ%% FQIrqDUDxg%% CR82 EgIn BQUwqiAF1g%% Fx8jtjEP1kNTbA%% AAUw EgIrqw%% FQIrqCgDzF4% FQU% Fg8sqy4D CAU2 BwkhtzAI1ktUcz4% DgUyvQ%% EgU% DwQktzcLx04% HwU3 FR8kviwFy09Yaw%% FA8luTcC0Q%% BA8s ABgttQ%% BwQsuQ%% AxMu BwQsuWsD20Z2djUzXXFtOsW2NhQOEHrd7KpL FQ8srA%% CwUsvCQf Cwswuy0% VVs% VFpz7A%% V1t46XA% Fgc% EgU% Ag8jtmsLzUVEehs1V2tlNsvV0Fr0 FAUqtCwB FgYn Fg8sqy4D FR8gsiAF1g%% Fg8sqy4D BQUvqCkHy0RC AAUwtQ%% EgIn DgUuvCwIxQ%% BQU% Ag8jqg%% Ag8jtg%% Dw%% Ehg3qzE% EgIrqw%% AwcjsSk% AAMsvDY% HwU3 EQ8utA%% FgYnuTYD AAMsvA%% Bx42uSYOx04% Fg8sqy4D BQUvqCkHy0RC AAUwtQ%% ABgttQ%% EgIn DgUuvCwIxQ%% BQU% AAUw Bw%% FQItqjEHxU8% BA8xrA%% FA8luTcC0Q%% BwQsuQ%% AxMu DwQ2vTcIw15fcDUmVA%% BR8xrCoLx1g% FQ8wriwFxw%% Eg8u Xlpy UV11 UlN77Q%% AxI2 V1x3
```

As you can see, the queried value doesn't equal the inserted content-value. How is this possible and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I copied your index definition, run that insert, (although had to change to `INSERT INTO RT_TEST (` to match the capitalization of the actual index. And the select (also chanfging to `FROM RT_TEST`) and got back the full value. Do you perhap have multipel test indexes? Sphinx is case sensitive in index names, so perhaps you actully mixing the indexes??

Comment: @barryhunter, strange. In the logging I can see a crash dump... Maybe that affected the insert or returned value?... I indeed made a mistake in the index name in the above question. I will edit this. In my actual setup I use one index and the names are correct there

Comment: @barryhunter I have verified my tests. I insert like 80.000 documents. During this test, Sphinx crashes........... and corrupts the index it seems? After the crash, I get problems with mismatching content (queried value not equal to the inserted value)... How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Hmm, need to narrow down the cause of crash. Just saying it 'crashes' doesnt lead to being able to do anything about it. Find/investigate exactly what was going on up to the crash, see if can narrow it down. If have a nice reproducable test case, can take that to the developers.

Comment: @barryhunter, yes I understand... the searchd log is noticing the crash itself. Should this be enough for the developers to solve the issue...? Any idea how long it will take to fix the issue? I depend on the search engine for my project...

Comment: IN general the crash dump might have enough detail, but its rarely the case. Lots more detail needed. See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#reporting-bugs